# Why didn't this ash tree's leaves grow in completely?

Tags: trees, leaves, pests

This ash tree grew healthy leaves for the past two years. This year the outer leaves didn't fill in. What could be the problem? I don't see D-shaped holes from ash borer in the bark. We did scuff up the tree somewhat last year, putting honeybee swarm traps in it and removing swarms.

USDA zone 5a/4b, central NY. Lots of trees seem to die off near our house - butternut, elm, ash. We have heavy clay soil near a swampy area.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does indeed look like Emerald Ash Borer damage. Typically, like with Bornze Birch Borer, the tree will put out lots of new growth in the bottom third of the canopy as the branches higher up die (this is especially visible in the first picture). You won't see the D-shaped holes at this point because they're in the upper canopy, not near the ground. I had four mature ashes die over three years, so I recognize the signs. Your tree is, unfortunately, a dead tree growing at this point. Sorry.

Comment: The only upside is that if the tree is cut to the ground and not stumped it will sucker and grow at enormous speed.  I have seen ash trees left for dead that were 3' tall the next year and 20' tall after three or four years.

Comment: @kevinskio True, and then they'll succumb to the borer again several (or more) years later. This is a similar cycle to that of the American chestnut blight (which is why that tree isn't close to extinction - they get big enough to set seed before they die-back again). It's also somewhat similar to Dutch Elm Disease, as it doesn't seem to strike elms that are less than 20 years old. But who wants to cut down the same tree every 10 years? You also have to manage the sprouts from the stump so that you have only a single sprout grow into a tree.

Comment: in other times and places this is called coppicing.  Apparently "The wood is renowned for its strength and flexibility for building, furniture-making, garden tools, farming equipment, weapons and musical instruments." https://www.eatweeds.co.uk/ash-fraxinus-excelsior

Comment: @Jurp Arg. Well, good to know it's Ash Borer. This particular tree wasn't our favorite anyway, but it's one of only a couple providing shade near the house. A new tree of a different kind is scheduled to be planted at some point. Question: Any tips for how to prevent Borer spread to a young healthy-looking Ash growing about 150' away?

Comment: @kevinskio Thanks for the info! Two years ago we felled some mature ash growing within a few feet of the foundation, so I know firsthand they're powerful regrowers. Didn't know they could be coppiced, though I've wondered about coppicing our shrubby swamp willows. We don't want to lose shade so we may take the "let it sucker" route.

Comment: The only way to prevent the spread of borer to another ash is via a neonicotinomide called imidicloprid (spelling may be wrong). This is a systemic insecticide that is ok for ashes because they're wind-pollinated, but will kill pollinators if used with flowering plants. This is often applied as a drench around the base of the tree, although I suspect that the tree you're referring to is already a host to the borer because it is so close to this tree.

Comment: In regards to coppicing, a strategy that you may use is to cut this tree down ASAP (if it dies completely it will NOT regenerate from the stump) and plant its replacement this fall (best) or next spring. Allow only ONE sprout of the ash to grow tall for a few years (as kevinskio noted, it will almost leap out of the ground) while the new tree gets established. After 4-5 years,. cut down the ash, treat the stump with triclopyr to prevent resprouting, and enjoy your new tree.